# Unable to fetch data for a many to many table property

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Hi I please need help.

I'm using ASP.Net Core 3.0 and EF Core... and I need to Edit a many to many table that has a navigation property.

I tried the below code, I can fetch the Invoice data but I'm getting null on the **ProductInvoices** property which is also a link to a many to many relation tables.

```
        // GET: Invoices/Edit
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {

            var invoice = await _context.Invoices.Where(i => i.InvoiceId == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            return View(invoice);
        }
```

```
    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }

        public int ProductsItemInStock { get; set; }

        public decimal CostPerItem { get; set; }

        public string ItemName { get; set; }

        public IList<ProductInvoice> ProductInvoices { get; set; }
    }


    public class Invoice
    {
        [Key]
        public int InvoiceId { get; set; }

        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }

        public Guid CreateByUser { get; set; }

        public int TotalInvoice { get; set; }

        public IList<ProductInvoice> ProductInvoices { get; set; }
    }
    
        public class ProductInvoice
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
        public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {

        var invoice = await _context.Invoices.Include("ProductInvoices").Where(i => i.InvoiceId == id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        return View(invoice);
    }
```

Comment: Can you advise me a good tutorial where I can learn EF Core please? cause I did read MSDN Official documentation for EF Core but I couldn't find that

Comment: MSDN documentation is the complete resource but for newbie you can learn by watching youtube videos around topics , but best way is to learn by doing. You can follow https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/ but be sure to practice.

Comment: You can also use lambda version like _context.Invoices.Include(x=>x.ProductInvoices)